# Displaying a text file one line at a time waiting for user input

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I have been struggling to find a way request that a user press "a key" (could be any key ideally, or just enter) and I ended up with the do while as follows

```
do { 
  cout << '\n' <<'Press a key to continue...'
} while (cin.get() != '\n')
```

Now the application of that I am looking to achieve is one in which I can read a .txt to a string which is then push_back() to a vector where I can use some form of looping to display the push_back line one at a time waiting for user input inbetween displaying lines

I have worked my way to a for do while loop with which I was hoping to get some advice

```
int main()
{
  vector<string> v;
  ifstream input("filetobedisplayed.txt")
  string line;

  while (getline(input, line))
    v..push_back(line);

  for (int i =0; i <v.size(); i++)
    do
    {
      cout << '\n' <<'Press a key to continue...'
    } while (cin.get() != '\n')

  cout >> v[i] >> endl;
}
```

Is this sufficient and if not where did I go awry?

Comment: A few things here. 1: Why is your indentation so utterly horrendous? 2: Where are your `{}`? 3: What's up with the `v..push_back`? That won't compile. 4: What is your question?

Comment: Agreed with @LightnessRacesinOrbit. No way this code will compile. Missing `;` too. Did you retype it here (wrong) or did you copy/paste code from your editor (correct)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for taking the time to say what I was going to type anyway. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've removed the vector portion because it doesn't seem to be necessary to print out a file line by line. If it is, push_back the line in the same loop as the print out. No need for two loops.

Note: Use `<<` with cout, not `>>`. `<<` = ship it out. `>>` = suck it in.

Note: C++ is a civilized language. We use double quotes, `"`, to delimit strings just the way the Giver Of Data intended. Single quotes, `'`, are reserved for characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("filetobedisplayed.txt"); //open file
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) //get line from file
    {
        // push_back(line); goes here if required.
        std::cout << line << std::endl; //print line
        std::cout << "Press a key to continue..." << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            //wait and discard all input until user hits enter
            // or enters a few billion keystrokes 
    }
}
```